# Can I use nextcloud as authorizing proxy?

Tags: reverse-proxy, nextcloud, authorization

I am thinking about setting up ethercalc and etherpad with my nextcloud instance to allow collaborative editing of text and spreadsheet documents. The ownpad plugin allows to embed etherpad into the nextcloud user interface, but the etherpad server is accessed directly by the client, so restricting access to etherpad means I have to configure authorization for etherpad as well as for nextcloud.

It would appear useful to me if I could configure nextcloud to forward (as a reverse proxy) requests to etherpad, but only if the request is tied to an active nextcloud session? I searched the internet for using nextcloud as reverse proxy, but actually only find information on using nextcloud behind a reverse proxy. As I want to use nextcloud authorization, running nextcloud and etherpad behind a reverse proxy does not seem to solve my problem.

Is there a plugin or configuration option for nextcloud that allows me to forward requests to an URL like `https://my.next.cloud/apps/proxy/ethercalc` to `http://localhost:8000/` if the request is in the context of an authenticated nextcloud session?

Comment: An excellent question. Have been grappling it myself, so far unsuccessfully.